# How to modify datetimepicker and add tooltip on hover?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am working on google events and I want to display them on date hover. I am using `datetimepicker`. But I have no idea how can I modify this. I checked an [example](https://www.learningjquery.com/2012/05/how-to-display-tooltip-on-jquery-ui) similar to this using `datepicker` but still no success.

```
$('#calendar').datetimepicker({
     format: 'L',
     inline: true,
})
```